# can't show image after use function runnable

Tags: android, imageview, handler, inputstream, runnable

i have problem with error on my code,

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

EditText et;
ImageView iv;
Runnable stream;
Handler hand = new Handler();
    Runnable run ;
    public Button tombol2;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
 Intent intent = getIntent();
     String url= intent.getStringExtra("URL");
tombol2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Drawable d1=LoadImageFromWebOperations(url);
iv.setImageDrawable(d1);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iv.setImageDrawable(d1);
        }
    }, 10000);
}
    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
{
     try
     {
         InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
         Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
         return d;
     }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exc="+e);
         return null;
     }  
}
```

}

i can't see image in my application after use runnable and handler function, i have error on side void run, `iv.setImageDrawable(d1);` how to fix it ? display and runnable that image

Answer (score 1):

First, your function do get the drawable should look like this:

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
{
    Drawable drawable = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
        drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
    }

    return drawable;
}
```

Now I don't understand the use of the Handler... If you want the image to appear after 10 seconds of activity creation, then use this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) MainActivity2.this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Drawable d1 = LoadImageFromWebOperations(url);
        iv.setImageDrawable(d1);
    }
}, 10000);
```

If not just use post() instead of postDelayed().

Comment: i get error on Drawable d1 = LoadImageFromWebOperations(url);

Comment: Check if you get d1 == null. If so you have a problem in `LoadImageFromWebOperations(url);` and need to debug it.